# Chrome Extension: URL not opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I am getting a dynamic URL which I want to open in new tab.

PS: I am currently writing this in content script. 
for example

```
  var newURL =  document.querySelectorAll("a")[lengthA].href
```

I want to open this in new tab. In javascript, We simple do window.open to open URL in new tab but it wasn't working, then I google the same and saw that in order to open URL in new tab, we need to do..

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
```

So I did the same i.e

```
  var newURL =  document.querySelectorAll("a")[lengthA].href
              chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
```

But even that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: chrome.tabs is not allowed in content scripts. You need an *event page* so your content script will send a message with the URL, and the event page script will use chrome.tabs.create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content script don't have access to all chrome API's so you would need to send a message to an event page.

Inside your content Script do like this to send a message to your event page

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({otab: "sendx", xname: newURL});
```

Now in your event page, you need to receive message to open this.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, senderResponse){
if (request.otab == "sendx") {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: request.xname });
  }
})
```

refer this document https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 1):

I made plenty of extensions with the intention of what you are doing and I used this:

```
function MyFunc() {
  var win = window.open("https://www.google.com", '_blank');
  win.focus;
}
```

if you add an event listener like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById("MyButton").addEventListener("mousedown", MyFunc);
});
```

It should work perfectly

Comment: In content Script?

Comment: @user9504869 sorry for not clarifying it, but yes in the content script.